Does typescript have a way to infer a Map's value type based on the key?
Let's say I have a Map with keys A and B that each store a boolean value, and keys X and Y that each store their own array of string. The simplest way to type this would be to write:
type CustomType = Map<string, boolean | string[]>

However, if I write the following code wherein I'll know the value type, TypeScript will be uncertain of the values type:
for (const [key, value] of MyMap) {
  switch(key) {
    case 'A' || 'B':
      // value will only be boolean but typescript thinks the value
      // could still be a string[],
      break
    case 'X' || 'C':
      // and vice versa.
      break
  }
}

Using a union as the following tells TypeScript that the Map as a whole will only be one or the other:
type CustomType = Map<'A' | 'B', boolean>
                | Map<'X' | 'Y', string[]>

Switching to intersection type seems to ignore the second half.
type CustomType = Map<'A' | 'B', boolean>
                & Map<'X' | 'Y', string[]>

Does TypeScript have a way to properly type this that doesn't require adding unnecessary type checks or littering my code with @ts-ignore comments?

No, typescript won't support this kind of typing with Map. Usually maps are for storing large numbers of items that all have the same type. If you want specific properties with specific types, you probably want an object type instead.

If an object type is acceptable, does this answer your question? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYBVzQLwCgpQBKEAxsgE4AmAPAOQCCtUAPlLQEK0A0UARssgA2EAIYA7AHxQAZPiKkKNWgA0mrWgE1uUJOQCWYgOYBtALoTcuSqUEjy0MmKRQAbiMFwIALliIUGLEs3DwgAOnpcAHpIggIAPQB+IPdPUI0omNjE3CA If so I can I write an answer about that.
